# Loops in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python

I apologize ahead of time for my ignorance but I have trying to code something in python that requires a question to be asked to the user and the user responds. Dependent on that response, the program should print a response and repeat the question until the correct answer is provided. I'm using Python 3.4.3

```
print("Enter Password")
password = input("Enter Password: ")
if password == 'Hello':
    print("Enter Name")
else:
    print("Wrong Password")

name = input("Type your name, please: ")
```

What's happening is even if I don't put in "hello", it continues and doesn't re-ask the question and prints wrong password and then goes to type your name please.... What am I missing? Please and thank you and again I'm sorry, I'm extremely new to this.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635073/validating-user-input-strings-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a loop in your code. You have a conditional (`if/else`), but no loop. A loop would be something like a [`while`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) statement or a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) statement.

```
password = input("Enter Password: ")
while password != "Hello":
    print("Wrong Password")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
name = input("Type your name, please: ")
```

---

This will loop until your `password` variable equals `Hello` (capitalization matters!)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using a loop so your code is executing sequentially. Using a `while` loop seems best here.

```
while True:
  print("Enter Password")
  password = input("Enter Password: ")
  if password == 'Hello':
    break
  else:
    print("Wrong Password")

name = input("Type your name, please: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops until "Hello" is entered. You need to use a loop: `for` or `while`

Just added while instead of if, and flipped the consequential actions

```
print("Enter Password")
password = input("Enter Password: ")
while password != 'Hello':
    print("Wrong Password")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
else:
    print("Enter Name")
    name = input("Type your name, please: ")
```