# How would I force user input to be only 1 and 0 in my code

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, input

So im trying to force the user to give me purely an input between 1 and 0 and I managed to do so for the most part but it'll only work if all three inputs are above that and my code only gives me and input for a

```py
def AND(a, b):
    return a and b

def OR(a, b):
    return a and b
    
    
def NOR(a, b):
    return a and b
        
    
user=[]
    
def main():
    a= False
    b= False
    c= False
    n_attempts = 1
    for _ in range(n_attempts):
        
        a_raw = input("for a, 1 or 0: ")
        try:
            a = int(a_raw)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid value for 'a': {a!r}")
            continue
        b_raw = input("for a, 1 or 0: ")
        try:
            b = int(b_raw)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid value for 'a': {b!r}")
            continue
        c_raw = input("for a, 1 or 0: ")
        try:
            c = int(c_raw)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid value for 'a': {c!r}")
            continue
    
        
    print ("Result of (A NOR B) OR (B AND C) is: " , int(OR(NOR(a, b), AND(b, c))))
    

    
main()
```

i tried if and elif statements and also work to some degree where itll activate if all inputs are above 1 or 0

```py
for _ in range(3):
    a=input("for a, 1 or 0: ")
        
    b=input("for b, 1 or 0: ")
        
    c=input("for c, 1 or 0: ")
    if a =="0" or a=="1":
        break
    else:
        print("wrong input")
    if b =="0" or b=="1":
        break
    else:
        print("wrong input")
        
    if c =="0" or c=="1":
        break
    else:
        print("wrong input")
```

im supposed to writethe code as blocks in functions that will perform each gate.  There will be one gate per function.  Pass the inputs to the functions and the outputs from the functions.

[image: This is my reference for the gate]

using that as a reference

Comment: What? I don't understand your question at all. How do you *force* the user to input what you want?

Comment: What don't you use argparse with choices=[0, 1]?

Comment: Are you aware that the `AND`, `OR` and `NOR` functions are identical?  They all return the same thing: `return a and b`

Comment: Is your question about the logic gate image at the bottom, or how to get inputs between 1 and 0 for a, b, and c?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating user input strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635073/validating-user-input-strings-in-python)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want to do.

```
a=bool
b=bool
c=bool

while True:

    v=["1","0"]
    a=input("input 1 or 0: ")
    b=input("input 1 or 0: ")
    c=input("input 1 or 0: ")
    if (a and b and c in v):
        break
    else:
        print("wrong input")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to keep asking for a valid input until it gets one. Use a `for` loop to iterate through the names and store input values in a dict to avoid duplicate code:

```
values = {}
for name in 'a', 'b', 'c':
    while True:
        try:
            value = input(f'for {name}, 1 or 0: ')
            value = values[name] = int(value)
            assert value in (0, 1)
            break
        except (ValueError, AssertionError):
            print(f"Invalid value for '{name}': {value!r}")

print(values['a'], values['b'], values['c'])
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AcclaimedYawningExpertise

Answer (score 0):

you should not direct assignment the value of input to a or b or c

```
value = input("some description here")
if value in ["0", "1"]:
    a = int(value)
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm assuming a lot here, but I gather that what you want is code that does the thing in the logic gate image. I recommend working backwards from `Q`.

(I'm using empty parentheses for placeholders.)

So, for the first one back from `Q` is `or`. So `()or()`. A function for that would be

```
def or_function(a, b):
    return a or b
```

Using that function would make it `or_function((), ())`.

Then, it's `A nor B`, or `not (A or B)` on the top. `(not (A or B)) or ()` Similarly, a function for that would be

```
def nor_function(a, b):
    return not(a or b)
```

Using functions, it would now be `or_function(nor_function(A, B), ())`.

Then, it's `B and C` on the bottom. The final answer is `(not (A or B)) or (B and C)`.

Since this seems to be your homework, I'll leave you to the last one - it should be fairly similar to the others.

Note: If input is 0 or 1, then you need to convert `0` to `False` and `1` to `True`.